# jQuery events function for 'html' but not CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        jQuery('#topcontrol').css({bottom:"15px"});
    } else {
        jQuery('#topcontrol').css({bottom:"-100px"});
    }
});

jQuery('#topcontrol').click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
    console.log('works');
});
```

Nothing happens. No errors in the console are shown. No matter what event - click, hover, etc - they only work if I apply them to the 'html' tag. First part of the code works perfectly, I mean the .css.

What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrr... I figured it out. The whole code needs to be included within this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Can anyone provide an explanation on this? Some images were not found, can that influence this?

Comment: Javascript will run as soon as it loads, but the rest of the page may not have loaded yet. That snippet you posted will wait until the document has fully loaded before executing the javascript contained within.